# Roman numbering in TOC, LOF and Appendix in LyX

Tags: numbering, lyx, roman-numerals

I would be grateful if you could tell me how to roman numbering in lyx of these pages where toc. lof and appendix are located.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i managed to solve it

[image]

However, I was wondering if there is a more "automatic" way in LyX